# Powershell - How to rename a file after moving it?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I am currently working on a project that requires that I move a file, and then rename it. I am using this code to move it and that is working. However, the rename portion is not taking place as it should. I cannot figure out why this isn't working. What have I goofed up? I have been beating my head against my desk for at least 20 minutes trying to figure this out.

```
# Variables for Watcher
$folder = "C:\Program Files\Whatever\Connector\Export\JobStatus"
$filter = '*.txt'
$date=(get-date -Format d) -replace("/")
$time=(get-date -Format t) -replace(":")

# Watcher + Settings                     
$fsw = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher $folder, $filter
$fsw.IncludeSubdirectories = $false
$fsw.NotifyFilter = [IO.NotifyFilters]'FileName', 'DirectoryName'

# Register Event (when file is created)
$onCreated = Register-ObjectEvent $fsw Created -SourceIdentifier FileCreated 
-Action {

# Foreach file loop 
ForEach ($f in $fsw)
{
    if (($File = Get-Item $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath | select -Expand 
Extension) -eq ".txt")
    {
        #Used for file testing - Opens the text file for 10 secs, then kills 
it.
        #Start-Process -FilePath $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath  | %{ sleep 
10; $_ } | kill


        # Variables for move   
        $folderpath = ($Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath | Split-Path)
        $folderfile = ($Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath | Split-Path -Leaf)
        $destination = "C:\Program Files\Whatever\Connector\Staging\"
        $newname = "job.import.$date"+"_"+"$time.txt"


    }

    # Variables for logging
    $logpath = 'C:\Program 
Files\Whatever\Connector\Export\JobStatus\outlog.txt'

    # Grab current file and move to "Staging" folder
    try
    {



        Get-ChildItem -Path $folderpath -Filter $folderfile | Move-Item - 
Destination $destination | sleep 5 | Write-Host Rename-Item 
$destination$folderfile -NewName $newname | Out-File -FilePath $logpath - 
Append
        Write-Host $destination$newname
        #sleep 5

        #Rename-Item "$destination $folderfile" -NewName $newname
        #Write-Host $destination $folderfile
        #"File $folderfile renamed to $newname" | Out-File -FilePath 
$logpath -Append

        # Log the move in logfile   
        "File $folderfile moved to $destination" | Out-File -FilePath 
$logpath -Append






    }

    # Log if errors + clear
    catch
    {
        $error | Out-File -FilePath $logpath -Append
        $Error.Clear()
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Why aren't you renaming the file *with* the move?  You're doing more steps than necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pipeline is broken when there's no object output.  `move-item` doesn't output an object unless the `-passthru` parameter is used.   Also, `set-sleep` doesn't output anything.  So, `rename-item` is never reached.

Replace the pipes after `move-item` and `sleep` with semicolons, and it should work.

Answer (score -1):

I actually fixed this removing the piped rename and replacing it with a 5 second sleep. I do the rename after the sleep and it works fine now. Still not sure why the rename wasnt working in the piped command though.